# MS Teams Bot Create Group Conversation

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I have added my app to specific team in MS Teams and added my bot there. Now, I am trying to create a chat between specific persons who were added to the 'General' channel using bot to communicate with only certain persons. For now, I am testing it by typing a command to that channel and processing activity like:

```
public async Task Handle(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Get all members who were added to that channel
    var members = new List<TeamsChannelAccount>();
    string continuationToken = null;

    do
    {
        var currentPage = await TeamsInfo.GetPagedMembersAsync(_turnContext, 100, continuationToken, cancellationToken);
        continuationToken = currentPage.ContinuationToken;
        members.AddRange(currentPage.Members);
    }
    while (continuationToken != null);

    // Start a new conversation with all of them
    var createdConversation = await _connectorClient.StartConversation(members, 
                                                                       _turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl, 
                                                                       _turnContext.Activity.Conversation.TenantId, 
                                                                       MessageFactory.Text("test proactive mssages"), 
                                                                       _turnContext.Activity.Recipient);
}
```

where `StartConversation` is:

```
public async Task<ConversationResourceResponse> StartConversation(List<TeamsChannelAccount> members,
                                                                          string serviceUrl,
                                                                          string tenantId,
                                                                          Activity activity,
                                                                          ChannelAccount botAccount,
                                                                          CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    AppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl, DateTime.MaxValue);
    var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceUrl), new MicrosoftAppCredentials(_botId, _botPassword));

    try
    {
        var conversationParams = new ConversationParameters(
            true,
            botAccount,
            members.Select(x => new ChannelAccount(x.Id, x.Name)).ToList(),
            "Test proactive group message",
            activity,
            new TeamsChannelData()
            {
                Tenant = new TenantInfo(tenantId)
            }
            , tenantId);

        return await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParams, cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

When I test this code, I receive the exception with the following message: **Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'** with Error Code "BadSyntax" and Message "Incorrect conversation creation parameters".

I'm not sure if that possible to create such conversations in MS Teams or not. The most confusing part for me is `isGroup` argument in `ConversationParameters` - doesn't that indicate that created conversation should be group chat? I've tried to create direct conversation with my account by setting `isGroup` to false and leaving only my `TeamsChannelAccount` in members and that worked

I am using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core 4.14.1

Thanks for reading and help!

Answer (score 1):

We tried it at our end and faced the same issue. Maybe you can try creating groups using deeplink https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat

Thanks